# TabBar continue button to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toolbar

I am trying to make a app where if a user will click on TabBar arrow icon he should go to a New activity. But don't known how to day that, i know how to go back using `onBackPressed()` function. Can any one let me know how to switch to another activity by click on that icon. 
Here is my MainActivity.

```
  bookinContinue = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolContinue);
    setSupportActionBar(bookinContinue);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    bookinContinue.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.sent);
    bookinContinue.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           onBackPressed();
        }
    });
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Continue");
```

Here is my Toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolContinue"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use intents to go to the next activity

**Example:**

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClassName.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
```